# Quick Sort implementation not working

Tags: c++

I currently need to implement quick sort in order to sort a vector of randomly generated doubles for analysis, i found the following code online a year or two ago and used it with another project successfully, but it's currently resulting in segmentation faults due to what i can only assume is infinite recursion. Any ideas why this might not be working?

```
void quickSort(vector<double>& array, int left, int right)
{
    //Declarations
    int low = left;
    int high = right;
    int pivot = array[(left + right)/2];

    //Partition
    while(low < high)
    {
        while (array.at(low) < pivot && low < right)
            low++;
        while (array.at(high) > pivot && high > left)
            high--;
        if(low <= high)
        {
            swap(array.at(low), array.at(high));
            low++;
            high--;
        }
    }

    // Recursion
    if(left < high)
        quickSort(array, left, high);
    if(low < right)
        quickSort(array, low , right);
}
```

*Code has be editted to implement some suggestions, it's not going out of bounds but only *mostly* sorts

Comment: Unrelated tip: Avoid cryptic and short identifier names, consider `low` and `high` instead of `i` and `j` respectively, for example.

Comment: Just FYI segmentation faults are unlikely to arise from infinite recursion, but very likely arise when writing to an array outside of its bounds (or any write to a referent you don't own)

Comment: Okay, how might this code be leaving the bounds of the vector, i honestly am stumped, the inputs into the initial sort are left = 0, and right = vector.size()-1, so i wouldn't think that'd cause an issue right?

Comment: Why not use `std::sort` ?

Comment: Because this is for an assignment in a class and i'm required to use quick sort

Comment: I'm pretty certain the intent of making you do a quicksort is so that you understand how quicksort *works!* You'll get no better understanding of how code works than running it through a debugger line-by-line until you find the issue. The fact that you found this code a couple of years ago and used it blindly, to the point where you're seeming unable to debug it, is clear indication that I'm right :-)

Comment: Not exactly using it blindly, and can readily describe how it works if i really needed to in order to prove a point, i more or less am unsure why this code seems to be leaving the bounds of a vector, which makes more sense than my first guess of infinite recursion.

Comment: Use `vector<t>::at` instead of the indexing operator `[]` to get a runtime bounds check, which will help you debug the problem and confirm it's an out-of-bounds issue and not something else: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: It's been solved, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Please do document how it was solved by providing an answer.